# Inconsistent crash dump - Win32

Tags: crash-reports, crash-dumps, disassembly

I have an user-mode application crash dump .mdmp file. I usually know how to handle it. Open with Visual Studio 2012 and it says problems was AV reading at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and points to command "cmp [RDX],0"

BUT, dump, as you know, contains registers and RDX points to valid address.

Question: how could that be and where this FFFFF comes from then ?

Thank you for attention !

Comment: I think the application (complicated C++ program) could manage memory buffers and swap it. Then the error actually happened in the page fault handler when it could not load the missing page.

Comment: I wonder if Mark Russinovich or Jeff Richter  read this #tag :)

Comment: Are you looking at RDX of the correct frame? I'm not very familiar with x86 assembly, but shouldn't you look at the memory where RDX points to?

Comment: I don't think Mark Russinovich and Jeff Richter are here on SO. I guess I would have seen them in the [tag:windbg] tag.